# can someone else overwrite my myapp.meteor.com deployment?

Tags: meteor

When deploying a meteorjs app to their server, for instance james.meteor.com, can someone else deploy their app to that same address and overwrite my project? or will it prompt them with a password?

If it does prompt them for a password, where can I set that password for my own apps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want

```
meteor deploy --password james.meteor.com
```